# How do I fix black window color after system update?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

I just upgraded a server from 2008 R2 to 2012 R2 and now all window colors are black:

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Is your Windows installation correctly activated after the upgrade?

Comment: @Sven: Yes, the installation is activated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once I switched to a different color scheme and then switched *back* to **Windows Basic**, the issue resolved itself.

Answer (score 0):

At first, see if your activation is ok. Then, you need to know that in order to change colors you need to have [Desktop Experience](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn609826.aspx) installed. However, it is not recommendable since it will also install another applications that you probably don't need and want on a server environment. One workaround is to modify *High Contrast White* theme instead of the *Windows Basic* theme.

I wouldn't concentrate on visual experience on the server's desktop at all as long as it doesn't prevent managing the server, but the activation is still something you should really check.

Comment: Yeah, I really don't want to install Desktop Experience on the server. The current state impacts being able to manage the server because you can't read text on title bars, which is at least very inconvenient.